# Using Taurus with Gatling fails with "Exception in thread "main" io.gatling.core.session.el.ElParserException"

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, blazemeter, taurus

I am trying to run Gatling with Taurus to experiment with it but it is not working as easily as expected.

I have this code:

```
 execution:
   - executor: gatling
   scenario: sample

 scenarios:
   sample:
     script: tests/gatling/BasicSimulation.scala
     simulation: tests.gatling.BasicSimulation
```

And using this gatling simulation scala code:

```
    package tests.gatling
    import io.gatling.core.Predef._
    import io.gatling.http.Predef._
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
      val httpConf = http
        .baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io")
.acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
        .doNotTrackHeader("1")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
      val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
        .exec(http("request_1")
        .get("/"))
        .pause(1)
      setUp(
        scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
      ).protocols(httpConf)
    }
```

When I run it wih this:

> bzt gatling.yml

It ends in error with:

```
08:13:02 ERROR: Child Process Error: Gatling tool exited with non-zero code: 1
...
Gatling STDERR:
Exception in thread "main" io.gatling.core.session.el.ElParserException: Failed to parse text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 with error '[B cannot be cast to [C'
    at io.gatling.core.session.el.ElCompiler.parseEl(ElCompiler.scala:249)
    at io.gatling.core.session.el.ElCompiler$.parse(ElCompiler.scala:171)
    at io.gatling.core.session.el.ElCompiler$.compile(ElCompiler.scala:174)
    at io.gatling.core.session.el.package$El$.el$extension(package.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.ValidationImplicits.stringToExpression(ValidationImplicits.scala:48)
    at io.gatling.core.ValidationImplicits.stringToExpression$(ValidationImplicits.scala:48)
    at io.gatling.core.Predef$.stringToExpression(Predef.scala:22)
    at tests.gatling.BasicSimulation.<init>(BasicSimulation.scala:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:558)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:79)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:59)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue a while ago and root cause was that I was using a jdk 9 , I downgraded to 8 and it worked.

I tried with your code and it works for me on jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [Taurus v1.12.1](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/releases/tag/1.12.1)

```
dt@aldan:/tmp> bzt gatling.yml 
09:32:29 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.12.1
09:32:29 INFO: Starting with configs: ['gatling.yml']
09:32:29 INFO: Configuring...
09:32:29 INFO: Artifacts dir: /tmp/2018-08-21_09-32-29.122174
09:32:29 INFO: Preparing...
09:32:30 INFO: Starting...
09:32:30 INFO: Waiting for results...
09:32:31 INFO: Waiting for finish...
09:32:43 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
09:32:43 INFO: Shutting down...
09:32:43 INFO: Post-processing...
09:32:43 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:13
09:32:43 INFO: Samples count: 2, 0.00% failures
09:32:43 INFO: Average times: total 0.065, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
09:32:43 INFO: Percentiles:
┌───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Percentile, % │ Resp. Time, s │
├───────────────┼───────────────┤
│           0.0 │         0.045 │
│          50.0 │         0.045 │
│          90.0 │         0.085 │
│          95.0 │         0.085 │
│          99.0 │         0.085 │
│          99.9 │         0.085 │
│         100.0 │         0.085 │
└───────────────┴───────────────┘
09:32:43 INFO: Request label stats:
┌──────────────────────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ label                │ status │    succ │ avg_rt │ error │
├──────────────────────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┤
│ request_1            │   OK   │ 100.00% │  0.085 │       │
│ request_1 Redirect 1 │   OK   │ 100.00% │  0.045 │       │
└──────────────────────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴───────┘
09:32:43 INFO: Artifacts dir: /tmp/2018-08-21_09-32-29.122174
09:32:43 INFO: Done performing with code: 0
dt@aldan:/tmp>
```

Other environment details:

- Gatling: [2.3.0](https://gatling.io/2017/08/31/gatling-2-3-0/) (downloaded automatically by Taurus)
- Java SE [1.8.0_151](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)

First of all try upgrading Taurus to the latest version like:

```
pip install --upgrade bzt
```

If it doesn't help you can try [building Gatling script from YAML config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Gatling/#Building-Test-Script-from-Config), check out [How to Load Test with Gatling and Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-gatling-and-taurus) guide for more details

Comment: It's because you're using Java 8, I am using Java 9

Comment: How can I point to a specific java version in taurus yaml? I want to run my gatling with Java test wrapped using taurus